# Exporting duplicate record fields

Tags: haskell, ghc

With `-XDuplicateRecordFields`, the following is allowed:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

module Baz(Foo(..), Bar(..)) where
data Foo = Foo {qux :: Int}    
data Bar = Bar {qux :: String}
```

However, I get a compile error when `Foo` is defined in a module `Foo` and `Bar` is defined in a module `Bar`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}

module Baz(Foo(..), Bar(..)) where
import Foo (Foo(..))
import Bar (Bar(..))
```

`Conflicting exports for ‘qux’`

I think what I'm trying to do is equivalent to the first example; it shouldn't matter where the data types are originally defined. Is this sort of thing supported in GHC 8?

Comment: This might well be a bug, which you [should report](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReportABug).

Comment: This could be a limitation of the implementation. Usually this extension is needed because you want to define two identically-named fields in the same module. Doing so in different modules was already OK, since it can be disambiguated using qualified import. Probably other cases like the one above were simply not considered by the GHC devs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did post a bug [here](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/13352). However, I also accidentally discovered a workaround:

If I put the pragma in *either* Foo.hs or Bar.hs, GHC accepts the program. That is, the following compiles:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DuplicateRecordFields #-}
module Foo(Foo(..)) where
data Foo = Foo {qux::Int}

module Bar(Bar(..)) where
data Bar = Bar {qux::String}

module Baz(Foo(..),Bar(..)) where
import Foo (Foo(..))
import Bar (Bar(..))
```